# c# Observable subject hot and cold

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I often have the situation where I want a UI element to "watch" an underlying value - supposing I am displaying an int - I want an an IObservable that I can subscribe to.

I have been using a Subject underneath, so I can just set it.  That works really well... except for the first time.  If I setup the subject - then later subscribe to it by opening a new UI element - it doesn't trigger an onnext until the next change.

I basically want something that works like a subject - but always and immediately does an onNext of the latest value to any new subscribers.

I know I can write such a construct myself - but it seems a common use case - is there something standard I'm missing?

Comment: I think you are looking for `BehaviorSubject<T>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want either `BehaviorSubject<T>` or `ReplaySubject<T>`.

`BehaviorSubject<T>` replays the single most recent value and requires that you give an initial value in the constructor.

You use it like this:

```
var bs = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
bs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
bs.OnNext(42);
bs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

That would output `0`, then `42`, then `42` to the console.

`ReplaySubject<T>` is a little more general. It allows you to specify the number of values to replay, but doesn't enforce that you provide an initial value.

```
var rs = new ReplaySubject<int>(1);
rs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
rs.OnNext(42);
rs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

This produces `42`, and then `42` to the console.

Compare this to a standard `Subject<T>`.

```
var s = new Subject<int>();
s.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
s.OnNext(42);
s.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

That just produces `42`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rx in UI, you should take a look at [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/).

It has handy extension `.ToProperty` and more:

```
_isValid = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Username, x => x.Password, (user, password) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)).ToProperty(this, x => x.IsValid);

public bool IsValid => _isValid.Value;
```

This is basically what you are doing:

- `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Property)` => property as observable
- `obs.ToProperty()` => observable to property that you can bind to UI

both work with `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: why downvotes? This basically answer "you don't have to reinvent the wheel"